# ruby to_yaml 2.0.0 adds !ruby/object:Hash but YAML.load won't read it

Tags: ruby, yaml

Is there a way to disable ruby 2.0.0 YAML's suffixing with ruby type info?

I just upgraded to ruby 2.0.0 and I'm having YAML problems. I read-update-write a yaml file that previously looked like this

```
test:
  test2:
    somevar: hello
```

When I feed this into ruby 200, it reads OK but writes:

```
test: !ruby/object:Hash
  test2: !ruby/object:Hash
    somevar: hello
```

When I rerun the program YAML.load reads nothing.

```
myH = YAML.load_file( YAML_FPATH )
puts "Yaml as Hash:" + myH.inspect
>> Yaml as Hash: {}
```

Curiously, if I pass the "test: !ruby/object:Hash" version of the file to ruby 1.8.7, it reads the suffixed file OK and writes a non-suffixed file.

Comment: A quick sanity test yielded the expected results here (ruby 2.0.0), e.g. `YAML.load({ test: { test2: { somevar: 'hello' }} }.to_yaml)` returned `=> {:test=>{:test2=>{:somevar=>"hello"}}}`, and `YAML.load('test: !ruby/object:Hash')` returned `=> {"test"=>nil}`.

Comment: Ah! If I write your 'altered' yaml block as a file and load it, it only sees the first level `test: {}`. However, I can load your original just fine and calling .to_yaml again on the result gives me valid output. How are you saving it?

Comment: My load & save code are:  
`   myH = YAML.load_file( YAML_FPATH )
   File.open( YAML_FPATH, 'w') { |outf|
       outf.write = myH.to_yaml
   }`

Comment: Ok, so I've run the following: `2.0.0-p195 :065 >  myH = YAML.load_file( YAML_FPATH )
 => {"test"=>{"test2"=>{"somevar"=>"hello"}}} 
2.0.0-p195 :066 >  File.open(YAML_FPATH, 'w') { |outf| outf.write(myH.to_yaml) }
 => 38 ` It works fine. Do you have anything weird like non-standard Hash classes, maybe?

Comment: P.S. I assumed you meant `outf.write(myH.to_yaml)` and not `outf.write = ...`

Comment: ... and the fun begins.  When I run      my_yaml = YAML.load_file( 'test_manifest.yaml' )         YAML after loading=" + my_yaml.to_yaml  using IRB, it comes out clean.  when I run the same code using     ruby tmp.rb it's also clean. When I run my whole program I get  !ruby/object:Hash added everywhere.   My program has exactly the same lines, back to back. Next I'll try trimming the program until the problem goes away.

Comment: Problem found:  I modified hash.to_yaml so that it sorts the keys. Since my code is based on hash.to_yaml 1.8.7 I need to revise it based on hash.to_yaml 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found: I modified hash.to_yaml so that it sorts the keys. Since my code is based on hash.to_yaml 1.8.7 I need to revise it based on hash.to_yaml 2.0.0.